# Firebird + EntityFramework com Visual Studio 2015

Tags: firebird

Olá, estou precisando criar uma conexão do firebird com visual studio, mas estou tendo problemas com a integração, procurei videos na internet, e só tem referência de 2012, não encontrei nada mais atual.

Estou querendo montar meu software com EntityFramework (edmx) pra facilitar nas transações com o banco, porém, não consegui criar a conexão ainda! Já adicionei o provider, mas quando vou criar meu arquivo EDMX não exibe a conexão Firebird.

PS:
Já instalei o bin no site do Firebird (o provider), verifiquei e o instalador ja adicionou os recursos no arquivo Machine.config

Desde ja agradeço,

Vou deixar dos links dos vídeos abaixo.
[Link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1WnuQ7gFQs)
[Link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lH6qHxambw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feche o seu Visual Studio e instale o **DDEX Provider for Visual Studio** e o **ADO.NET Data Provider**, ambos podem ser baixados no seguinte link:

https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/additional-downloads/

Após a instalação vá até o arquivo Machine.config localizado em `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config` para 32 Bits ou 
`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config` para 64 Bits

E procure por `<DbProviderFactories>` você vera que o instalador do DDEX inseriu duas linhas para o Firebird, remova uma e deixando apenas uma.

Segue um exemplo de como deve ficar:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```