# Firebird + EntityFramework - Problema para adicionar conexão

Tags: firebird, visual-studio-2015

Estou com problemas para adicionar uma conexão do Firebird no Visual Studio

Eu segui todo o passo a passo da documentação

1. Instalei FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
2. gacutil / i    FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
3. gacutil / i EntityFramework.Firebird.dll
4. editei e executei o arquivo de registro para o  VS2015
5. editei o  machine.config

Após isso o Firebird foi adicionado ao form de escolha do data source
[image]

Porém quando avanço para a configuração, o form que abre não é como esse da documentação: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fbdevgd-en/html/fbdg30-efw-vs-prepare.html#efw-database-locate

O VS abre este form[image]

Então eu tendei informar uma string de conexão, mas gera esse erro.
[image]

Tenho a impressão que o VS está carregando um form padrão.

Comment: Também tive problemas com o driver do Firebird. Eu usei a conexão por ODBC e deu certo.

Comment: Siga os processos indicado nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183409/firebird-entityframework-com-visual-studio-2015/186312#186312

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Firebird + EntityFramework com Visual Studio 2015](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183409/firebird-entityframework-com-visual-studio-2015)